# Two-way ANOVA Tukey Test and boxplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, multcompview

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/84-tukey-test.html) and this [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53038671/tukey-test-results-on-geom-boxplot-with-facet-grid), [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56136421/consistent-lettering-across-facets-for-tukey-letter-plot-on-ggplot) to plot a **Two-way box plot with facets** and the **letters** indicating the statical difference between the treatments. Does anyone know how to do this kind of graph?

Some code about my attempts:

```
    library(multcompView)
    library(ggplot2)
    #sample dataframe
    data <- structure(list(nozzle = c("XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", 
                                      "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", 
                                      "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", 
                                      "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", 
                                      "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR"), 
                           trat = c("Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", 
                                    "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 12.8", 
                                    "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 34", "Cle 34", 
                                    "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", 
                                    "Cle 12.8", "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 34", 
                                    "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 34", 
                                    "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 34"), 
                           adj = c("Without", "Without", "Without", "Without", "Without", 
                                   "Without", "Without", "Without", "With", "With", "With", 
                                   "With", "With", "With", "With", "With", "Without", "Without", 
                                   "Without", "Without", "Without", "Without", "Without", "Without", 
                                   "With", "With", "With", "With", "With", "With", "With", "With"), 
                           dw1 = c(3.71, 5.87, 6.74, 1.65, 0.27, 0.4, 0.37, 0.34, 0.24, 0.28, 0.32, 
                                   0.38, 0.39, 0.36, 0.32, 0.28, 8.24, 10.18, 11.59, 6.18, 0.2, 0.23, 
                                   0.2, 0.31, 0.28, 0.25, 0.36, 0.27, 0.36, 0.37, 0.34, 0.19)), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))    

    #function 
    generate_label_df <- function(TUKEY, variable){

      # Extract labels and factor levels from Tukey post-hoc 
      Tukey.levels <- variable[,4]
      Tukey.labels <- data.frame(multcompLetters(Tukey.levels)['Letters'])

      #I need to put the labels in the same order as in the boxplot :
      Tukey.labels$treatment=rownames(Tukey.labels)
      Tukey.labels=Tukey.labels[order(Tukey.labels$treatment) , ]
      return(Tukey.labels)
    }

    # What is the effect of the treatment on the value ?
model=lm( data$dw1~ data$trat:data$adj )
ANOVA=aov(model)

# Tukey test to study each pair of treatment :
TUKEY <- TukeyHSD(x=ANOVA, 'data$trat', conf.level=0.95)

# Tuckey test representation :
plot(TUKEY , las=1 , col="brown")

p <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=trat , y=dw1, fill=adj)) +  
      geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA) +
      facet_grid(~nozzle) +
      scale_fill_brewer(palette="Reds") +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(legend.position="none") +
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) 

    for (facetk in as.character(unique(data$nozzle))) {   
      subdf <- subset(data, as.array(nozzle==facetk))
      model=lm(dw1 ~ trat:adj, data=subdf)
      ANOVA=aov(model)
      TUKEY <- TukeyHSD(ANOVA)

      labels <- generate_label_df(TUKEY , TUKEY$`trat:adj`)
      names(labels) <- c('Letters','trat')
      yvalue <- aggregate(.~nozzle, data=subdf, quantile, probs=0.75)  
      final <- merge(labels, yvalue)
      final$nozzle <-  facetk

      p <- p + geom_text(data = final,  aes(x=trat, y=value_y, label=Letters), 
                         vjust=-1.5, hjust=-.5)
    }
    p
```

I'm getting this error

> Error in quantile.default(X[[i]], ...) : factors are not allowed

I know I have to put numbers, **not factors** in quantile but I don't know if I fix that error it will appear the letters in my graph.

Comment: How do you want to call the function?  What are `variable` and `TUKEY` arguments to the function?

Comment: Hi, @akrun I just follow the [r-graph tutorial](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/84-tukey-test.html), I have not developed the function, so I don't know how to answer you, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data <- structure(list(nozzle = c("XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", 
                                  "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", 
                                  "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", 
                                  "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", 
                                  "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR"), 
                       trat = c("Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", 
                                "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 12.8", 
                                "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 34", "Cle 34", 
                                "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", 
                                "Cle 12.8", "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 34", 
                                "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 34", 
                                "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 34"), 
                       adj = c("Without", "Without", "Without", "Without", "Without", 
                               "Without", "Without", "Without", "With", "With", "With", 
                               "With", "With", "With", "With", "With", "Without", "Without", 
                               "Without", "Without", "Without", "Without", "Without", "Without", 
                               "With", "With", "With", "With", "With", "With", "With", "With"), 
                       dw1 = c(3.71, 5.87, 6.74, 1.65, 0.27, 0.4, 0.37, 0.34, 0.24, 0.28, 0.32, 
                               0.38, 0.39, 0.36, 0.32, 0.28, 8.24, 10.18, 11.59, 6.18, 0.2, 0.23, 
                               0.2, 0.31, 0.28, 0.25, 0.36, 0.27, 0.36, 0.37, 0.34, 0.19)), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))    

data$trat_adj<-paste(data$trat,data$adj,sep = "_")
data<-as.data.frame(data[-c(2,3)])
str(data)
#function 
generate_label_df <- function(TUKEY, variable){

  # Extract labels and factor levels from Tukey post-hoc 
  Tukey.levels <- variable[,4]
  Tukey.labels <- data.frame(multcompLetters(Tukey.levels)['Letters'])

  #I need to put the labels in the same order as in the boxplot :
  Tukey.labels$treatment=rownames(Tukey.labels)
  Tukey.labels=Tukey.labels[order(Tukey.labels$treatment) , ]
  return(Tukey.labels)
}

p <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=data$trat_adj, y=data$dw1, fill=data$trat_adj)) +  
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA) +
  facet_grid(~nozzle) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Reds") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) 
p

for (facetk in as.character(unique(data$nozzle))) {   
  subdf <- subset(data, nozzle==facetk)
  model=lm(dw1 ~ trat_adj, data=subdf)
  ANOVA=aov(model)
  TUKEY <- TukeyHSD(ANOVA)
  labels <- generate_label_df(TUKEY, TUKEY$trat_adj)

  names(labels) <- c('Letters','data$trat_adj')
  yvalue <- aggregate(subdf$dw1, list(subdf$trat_adj), data=subdf, quantile, probs=.75)  

  final <- data.frame(labels, yvalue[,2])

  names(final)<-c("letters","trat_adj","dw1")
  final$nozzle <-  facetk

  p <- p + geom_text(data = final,  aes(x=trat_adj, y=dw1, fill=trat_adj,label=letters),
                     vjust=-1.5, hjust=-.5)
}
p
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work too. Maybe the problem is the function. Thank you @Jiang Liang.

Comment: I revised it. it works in here. @Vitor Muller Anunciato